# Recommended behaviour for update () method in DAO using EntityManager (JPA)?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, dao, entitymanager

I have a REST service with the basic CRUD methods to create/read/update/delete my resources.

My DAO implementation for update looks like this:

```
@Override
public Entity update(Entity entity) {
    final Entity updatedEntity = em.merge(entity);
    em.flush();
    return updatedEntity;
}
```

Now I don't want to "update" a resource that is not available in the database. To fix this, I wrote a service that first executes a get call for the resource with the provided id. If the resource is not available, it throws an exception that the resource can not be updated...

But this implies 2 database calls for every REST update call. Is there a recommended way to write a dao update() method that throws an exception if the entry already exists? Of is it accepted to create a new entry when performing a PUT for an unexisting resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merge() method persists an entity that is not persistent yet (doesn't have an ID or version), and updates the entity if it is persistent. You thus don't need to do anything other than calling merge() (and returning the value returned by this call to merge()).

Which means that, if the entity does not have an ID you persist on DB a new record.

```
    /**
     * Merge the state of the given entity into the
     * current persistence context.
     * @param entity  entity instance
     * @return the managed instance that the state was merged to
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if instance is not an
     *         entity or is a removed entity
     * @throws TransactionRequiredException if invoked on a
     *         container-managed entity manager of type
     *         <code>PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION</code> and there is
     *         no transaction
     */
    public <T> T merge(T entity);
```

> #### 3.2.4.1 Merging Detached Entity State
>
> The merge operation allows for the
>   propagation of state from detached
>   entities onto persistent entities
>   managed by the EntityManager.
>
> The semantics of the merge operation
>   applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing
>     managed entity instance X' of the same
>     identity or a new managed copy X' of X
>     is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created
>     and the state of X is copied into the
>     new managed entity instance X'.
> - If X is a removed entity instance, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>     thrown by the merge operation (or the
>     transaction commit will fail).
> - If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>     however, the merge operation is
>     cascaded to entities referenced by
>     relationships from X if these
>     relationships have been annotated with
>     the cascade element value
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`
>     annotation.
> - For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the
>     cascade element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>     `cascade=ALL`, Y is merged recursively
>     as Y'. For all such Y referenced by
>     X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note
>     that if X is managed then X is the
>     same object as X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL` is
>     not specified, then navigation of the
>     same association from X' yields a
>     reference to a managed object Y' with
>     the same persistent identity as Y.
>
> The persistence provider must not
>   merge fields marked LAZY that have not
>   been fetched: it must ignore such
>   fields when merging.
>
> Any `Version` columns used by the
>   entity must be checked by the
>   persistence runtime implementation
>   during the merge operation and/or at
>   flush or commit time. In the absence
>   of `Version` columns there is no
>   additional version checking done by
>   the persistence provider runtime
>   during the merge operation.

**1# Update Strategy**

```
public Entity update(Entity entity) {
    final Entity find = em.find(...);
    if(find == null){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    //set ID into entity
    updatedEntity = em.merge(entity);
    return updatedEntity;
}
```

**2# Update Strategy**

```
@Transactional
public Entity update(Entity entity) {
    final Entity find = em.find(...);
    if(find == null){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    //set into find each value that you want update
    //when the transaction is closed, it will be updated the entity
    return find;
}
```

Try to avoid em.flush() .. isn't a best practices.

Comment: In many cases #2 strategy is best option, the reason is that merge delta calculation is tricky, specially when you have @OneToMany -eager/lazy-relationships. Also keep in mind that #2 needs update the relations by hand.